# Is it possible to simplify this BASH eval expression?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Given the following Bash shell script excerpt:

```
# The intent is to take the PATH env variable, break it up into its parts, making them
# appear to be command line args (i.e., `$1`, `$2`, ...), and then for this example, just
# echo the parts in space delimited form, but we can imagine that we may want to do other
# things with them - this is just sample usage

# Important Requirement/Constraint
# ================================
# Please do not alter the "PATH to $1, $2, $3, ..." portion of the answer or replace the
# Bash ".." range construct with the output of the "seq" command exec'd in a subshell.
# Preferably, the answer should simply consist of the simplification of the last line of
# code - the "eval eval ..." . Also, please don't simplify by collapsing the whole thing
# to just echo "$@" since we may want to work with only some of the parts, and not
# necessarily the first parts, of the path. That is to say that the 1 and $# in the
# {1..$#} range could be replaced with other shell variables or expr., potentially

# Test case
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

# The code being examined follows

# Set ':' as the input field separator of the path
IFS=: # Or, more appropriately if in a function: local IFS=:

# Parse the PATH environment variable and break it up into its components
set $PATH

# This is the line we want to simplify, if possible, without losing functionality of
# course (see the comment that follows for details)
eval eval echo '\'$(eval 'echo "\${1..$#}"')

# Some notes and explanations regarding the functionality and underlying intent of the
# preceding line:
#   - We start by dynamically creating the following construct: ${1..3}
#     since $# is 3 for our example
#   - Use Bash to expand that construct to: $1 $2 $3
#     these vars contain the parsed parts of the PATH
#   - Finally, display the three parts of the PATH using echo: echo $1 $2 $3
#   - This causes the following text to be sent to STDOUT:
#     /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin
```

So, can the `eval eval...` line in the preceding code be simplified, but still produce the desired output, which for the above example is:

```
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin
```

I am thinking along the lines of a solution that would replace some of the `echo` commands with input/output redirection (perhaps) or maybe a reordering/collapsing of sorts that would lead to the need for fewer `eval` commands than are used in the example.

Comment: I'd go for the "collapsing of sorts" as hinted on by @oguz ismail.

Comment: @oguz, I explained that we may be interested in _some of the args_ and not all, that was a sample range equivalent to `"$@"`. See the last sentence of the `Requirement/Constraint` comment embedded into the code

Comment: Could you move the prose out of the code block? It's a lot easier to read when properly formatted.

Comment: Then you'd use something like `"${@:1:3}"`, not eval.

Comment: I would stick the path components into an array (why set it to positional parameters, requiring that unquoted expansion?) like `IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$PATH"` and then do with the `arr` array whatever I want.

Comment: @oguz, and when you parameterize your 1 and your 3 to be dynamic, you're right back at my original question

Comment: Then you use a C-style `for ((...))` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but still produce the desired output,
> /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin

Just:

```
echo "${PATH//:/ }"
```

> The intent is to take the PATH env variable, break it up into its parts, making them
> appear to be command line args (i.e., `$1`, `$2`, ...), and then for this example, just
> echo the parts in space delimited form, but we can imagine that we may want to do other
> things with them - this is just sample usage

I do not trust unquoted shell expansions.

```
IFS=':' read -ra patharr <<<"$PATH"
set -- "${patharr[@]}"
IFS=' '; printf "%s\n" "${patharr[*]}"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, but I do like your answer, so have an extra up-vote on top.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "${PATH}" | tr ':' '\n' > stack

count=1

echo "#/bin/sh-" | tr '-' '\n' >> stack2 

while read line 
do
echo "path${count}=${line}" >> stack2
count=$(($count+1))
done < stack

source stack2
```

Now you've got every section of the path, in its' own named variable.

Comment: Not *exactly* what I asked for, but interesting enough for an up-vote.

Comment: Narcissistic supply is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking close to the original, you can do

```
IFS=:
set $PATH
echo "$@"
```

If you don't want to change `IFS` and `PATH`, you can do

```
set $(sed 's/[^=]*=//;s/:/ /g' <<< ${PATH})
echo "$@"
```

Comment: You've got one semicolon too many in there, my friend. It should be: `set $(sed 's/[^=]*=//;s/:/ /g' <<< ${PATH}); echo "$@"` . Certainly an interesting take, if not within the guidelines of the question. Have an up-vote, in any case (*and replace that second semicolon in the sed command with a colon - this isn't Windows*).